# Roll-off of a third-order active filter

Tags: filter, transfer-function, math, active-filter, cutoff-frequency

I've a third order active filter, without zeros. I know that when \$f=0\$ the gain response is \$1\$. So the cutoff-frequency is located at:

$$\left|\text{H}\left(\omega_0\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega_0=\dots\tag1$$

The roll-of of the filter can be found by using:

$$\text{roll-of}=20\log_{10}\left(\left|\text{H}\left(\omega_2\right)\right|\right)-20\log_{10}\left(\left|\text{H}\left(\omega_1\right)\right|\right)\tag2$$

In order to get dB/decade I need to have:

$$10\omega_2=\omega_1\tag3$$

And in order to get reasonable values we need to have:

$$\omega_2>\omega_1>>\omega_0\tag4$$

And I know that when \$f\to\infty\$ the roll-of tends to \$-60\$ dB/decade

> Let's say I need a accuracy for the roll-of, up to 4 decimal places. What value for \$\omega_1\$ should I pick? And is there a resource that I can check out to read more about this?

Comment: roll-off of -60 dB/decade to *4 decimal places* is unlikely achievable due to component parasitics, and construction PCB parasitics.

Comment: what are your passband and stop band breakpoints and attenuation + tolerances. e.g. .1dB ripple PB and -20dB stop band with 3rd order slope on one side?  Breakpoint accuracy is determined by component tolerances.  Slope 1 decade away is gauranteed by design. Your specs are meaningless.

Comment: Have you solved this for a 2nd order simpler filter rather than jump straight in?

Comment: @glen_geek if you had to, you could calibrate and tune a filter pole to four decimal places and use multiple components (ie 1uf 20nf and 47pf) to get the exact pole, it would take some work